# Searching a tuple in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, tuples

We have a csv file :

```
1, 3, 4, 6
5, 3, 1, 9
3, 2, 4, 1
```

For example we have a tuple with n items. For example if `n=2` we have a tuple like `(1,3)`.

How can we find, how many times the (1,3) exists in our CSV file? In this example `(1,3)` exists 2 times. In row 1 as `(1,3)` and in row 2 as (3,1). How we can do this in Python, if we have a tuple with `n` items?

Answer (score 0):

First, read your CSV file in. I'm assuming it will fit in memory.
Then use a dictionary to count occurrences of tuples. I use a defaultdict for convenience.
   csv = [[j.strip() for j in i.split(',')] for i in csv.splitlines()]

Then there are a couple approaches:

```
import collections
import operator
a = collections.Counter([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in reduce(operator.add,[zip(line[0:-1],line[1:]) for line in csv])]).most_common()
```

or

```
import collections
b = collections.defaultdict(lambda:0)
for line in csv:
    for pair in zip(line[0:-1],line[1:]):
        b[tuple(sorted(pair))]+=1
```

I like the first approach better since it's sorted although seems a little cryptic. a yields:

```
[(('1', '3'), 2),
 (('2', '3'), 1),
 (('4', '6'), 1),
 (('3', '5'), 1),
 (('1', '4'), 1),
 (('3', '4'), 1),
 (('1', '9'), 1),
 (('2', '4'), 1)]
```